# Prove that $\mathrm{Res}(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}, z_0) = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Show that if $f$ and $g$ are analytic on a neighborhood of $z_0$ with
>   $f(z_0)\not= 0$ and $z_0$ is a simple zero of $g$, then we have
>   $\mathrm{Res}(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}, z_0) = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$.

I know that $\mathrm{Res}(f,z_0)+a_{-1}= \int_{C_p} \frac{f(z)dz}{z-z_0}$, where $C_p$ is simply the circle at $z_0$ with radius of convergence $p$ ($0<p<r$) in positive direction.

How could I prove this exercise? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a corollary of the following theorem:

> If $f:U \to \mathbb{C}$ is meromorphic and has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0 \in U$, then $$\operatorname{Res}(f;z_0) = \frac{1}{(m-1)!} \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}} (z-z_0)^m f(z)$$

Proof: Consider $$(z-z_0)^m f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^{m-1} a_{j-m} (z-z_0)^j + g(z)(z-z_0)^m$$, where $g(z)$ is some holomorphic function in a neighbourhood of $z_0$. Differentiating both sides to order $m-1$ yields the desired result.

As for $g/h$, we have
$$ \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{f}{g};z_0 \right) = \lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0) \frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \lim_{z \to z_0} f(z) \frac{z-z_0}{g(z) - g(z_0)} = \frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}
$$